# How to connect to an API via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, security

I'm trying to connect to Bitly via JavaScript, but I'm worried that my token will be visible to anybody who can view my script. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you read their [API documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html)?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using OAuth 2.0 protocol, as it's recommended. Perhaps, should I change it ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don´ t have a static site, just use your server as a proxy.
Create a route on your server that will be requested by the javascript code (without the token).
Your Server requests the API with the token and sends the awnser back to the JS-Client:

`JS-Client <--> Your Server <--> API`

This way your API Token remains on your server only. But you should also think about an authentication
mechanismn for your server route (eg. session) to avoid abuse of your "Proxy".

Comment: I'm using a static gh-pages website.

Answer (score 1):

Your token is transmitted using HTTPS to the bitly API. This means that your data transfer between the web browser and API servers is encrypted. This is invisible to you and you do not need to do anything special, but like you say, the token can be viewed if it is kept in the javascript.

You do not want to call the bitly API directly from javascript. You need to create your own proxy service that makes the requests on the web browsers behalf. Your service will have access to the token, the web browser will not. This way you can also manage your users permissions your self.

In a nut shell your web browser makes requests to your own service, then your service makes the requests to bitly. Your proxy service passes the result back to the browser minus the token.